# Azure Synapse .NET C# Sparkpool: Fail to start interpreter

Tags: c#, azure, azure-synapse, spark-notebook, .net-spark

When I am working on a .NET Spark (C#) Notebook in Azure Synapse I always get the following error message: `Fail to start interpreter. detail: org.apache.spark.api.dotnet.DotnetBackend`. When changing the language from .NET Spark (C#) to Python or Scala the notebook is working as expected.

What is causing this error?

[image]

I have tried:

- Working in a completely new resource group
- Working with a larger Spark Node
- Running the notebook `Hitchhiker's Guide to .NET for Apache Spark` available via the Gallery
- Search online for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Use spark 3.2 runtime.

I asked the same question on the microsoft Q&A where I got a working solution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179148/azure-synapse-net-c-sparkpool-fail-to-start-interp